# Parsing AWS push notifications in swift

Tags: php, swift, amazon-web-services, push-notification

We hired a remote developer to add push notifications to our ios app. We already have it working with Android, so we know that there is not a problem with the service or our API, but the developer is insisting that we need to change the message coming into the ios app on our end.

Here is the php:

```
private function sendNotifications($recipients, $type, $id) {
  require_once 'aws.phar';

  try{
    $client = Aws\Sns\SnsClient::factory(array(
      'region' => '#######',
      'version' => '###########',
      'credentials' => [
      'key'    => '##################',
      'secret' => '####################################'
      ],
      'scheme' => 'http'
    ));

    foreach($recipients as $recipient) {
      $topicName = $recipient;
      $topicArn = '####################################'.$topicName;

      $alert = "Somebody just left you a message";
      if($type == "like") {
        $alert = "Somebody liked your message";
      }else if($type == "reply") {
        $alert = "Somebody replied to your message";
      }

      $message = '
      {
        "type" : "' . $type . '",
        "id" : "' . $id . '"
      }
      ';

      try{
        $result = $client->publish(array(
        'TopicArn' => $topicArn,
        'Message' => $message
        ));
      }catch(Exception $e2) {
        // Topic doesn't exist
      }
    }
  }catch(Exception $e) {
    $this->log($e->getMessage());
  }
}
```

Here is the snippet that I asked him to send me:

```
// Push notification received
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification data: [AnyHashable : Any]) {


let aps = data[AnyHashable("aps")] as? NSDictionary


let alert = aps?.value(forKey: "alert") as? String
print(alert)
let alert2 = convertToDictionary(text: alert!)


let type = alert2!["type"] as? String
let id = alert2!["id"] as? String

var messageAlert = ""
if type != nil {


switch type! {
case "message":
messageAlert = "Somebody just messaged you"

case "reply":
messageAlert = "Somebody replied to your message"

case "like":
messageAlert = "Somebody liked your message"

default:
messageAlert = "Somebody just messaged you"
}

}



UserDefaults.standard.set(id, forKey: "MessageIDFromNotification")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()


NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("UserNotification"), object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("openedFromNotification"), object: nil)

if application.applicationState == .inactive || application.applicationState == .background {

if((UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: USER_DEFAULTS_USERTOKEN) as? String) != nil)
{
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController

let tabbar = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AMTabBarVC") as! AMTabBarVC
tabbar.selectedIndex = 0
tabbar.InitialVCindex = 0

tabbar.selectBackgroundForItem(at: 0, backgroundColor: UIColor.red, withEarlySelect: true, animated: false)

navigationController?.pushViewController(tabbar, animated: true)
}
}

}



func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
// Convert token to string
let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
UserDefaults.standard.set(deviceTokenString, forKey: "deviceToken")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
print("Device Token Registered: \(deviceTokenString)")




}
```

I am unfamiliar with Swift, so I'm not sure how this should look, but developer is insisting:

right now you are sending like :

{
"aps": {
"alert": "{\n \"type\" : \"message\",\n \"id\" : \"109556\",\n \"alert\" : \"Somebody just messaged you\"\n }",
"sound": "default"
}
}

but you need to send like :

{
    "aps": {
        "alert": "Somebody just messaged you",
        "sound": "default",
        "type": "message",
        "id": "109556"
    }
 },

When I asked him why he couldn't just parse the json he replied:

for iOS its default that whatever information you are passing in an alert it will be displayed in the notification.
we cannot preprocess notifications like android. as its restriction on iOS

Can this be fixed in the swift code? The whole thing feels weird to me...

Comment: Did you read documentation on Apple push notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your developer is correct - Apple is looking for specific keys in order to process the push notifications.  The payload *can* be parsed to get user-defined keys and values and to react accordingly, but the basic things like `alert`, `sound`, `badge` need to be structured as your developer is telling you so that the phone can display them to your users when the app is in the background.

Full details in Apple's [Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH10-SW1).

Comment: As a small aside, that's not a very safe way of handling the notifications, and you should also use Swift objects rather than the old, Objective-C objects like `NSDictionary`.